# java: do not start another thread while current alive

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have main thread with method "start". This method starts another thread, that doing long job. Method "start" can be call from another threads. How to avoid creating new threads in "start" method if already have one running and do not lock main thread? I trying use singleThreadExecutor, but it queues tasks.

code:
Start method:

```
 public void start(){
// need only one active thread
// if thread alive, avoid to start another
        t = new Thread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);     
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();      
    }
```

Simple test

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Thread r = new Thread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Helper.getInstance().start();
                }
            });
            r.start();      
   }
```

Comment: Use a thread pool with a size of 1

Comment: So do you want to queue the second job if the thread is already running, or just ignore it?

Comment: SingleThreadExecutor doesn't queue threads. It queues tasks (however in your case you've probably mistakenly made your tasks into threads).

Comment: @Thilo just ignore it

Comment: You could try `ExecutorService.submit(Runnable)` which will return `Future` and then check if `Future.isDone()`

Comment: @Kayaman, my mistake, of course it queues tasks

Comment: You could check if `t != null && t.isAlive()` before you start another one. Or use a SingleThreadExecutor and configure it not to queue, but discard.

Comment: @Thilo, thanks, `ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy()` helped me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just discard new tasks when the current thread is busy, you could use a SingleThreadExecutor and configure it to [discard any overflow tasks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy.html) instead of queueing them.